# How can I add a dynamic date time picker to my app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a web app that supports online reservation/booking system. I want to create a dynamic date picker that allows the user to pick some specific dates, based on the availability.

Let's say the data for available dates is stored in an array `slots`. How can modify the date picker to only allow the user to choose from set of these dates, while disabling the rest.

I'm use DatePicker from `@material-ui/pickers` and I was able to find `disablePast` which disables all the previous dates but couldn't find any prop, that fits my use case.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: DatePicker has `shouldDisableDate`. Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492979/13199774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do for your this is, you can use the `shouldDisableDate` prop in which you have to pass a function that accepts `date` as an argument and return a boolean `true/false` whether the date should be rendered or not.

For example:

In your component's `shouldDisableDate` prop you can pass a function like this

```
<DatePicker  
  shouldDisableDate={renderDateFunction}
  ...
```

and then define the function as

```
const renderDateFunction = (renderDate) => {
    
   // If the current date passed to this function is included in the slots
   // then enable selection of that date
   if(slots?.includes(renderDate)) return true;

   // else prevent the user from selecting that date
    return false;
  };
```

You can read more about the DatePicker Component API from the documentation here : https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.